# Java inversion of control on an MVC based application

Tags: java, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm building an MVC based java application/game and trying to use IoC to separate object creation from application logic.

Let's assume I have just 2 entity  : `Board` and `Player` where 
each one has a `Model` class, a `View` class and a `Controller` class.

The `BoardModel` needs a `PlayerModel` (to handle some app logic) and the `BoardView` needs a `PlayerView` (to render it inside its space ).

To create a new `Player` I use a `PlayerFactory`  class that creates the `PlayerModel`, the `PlayerView` and the `PlayerController` and wires them together.

The problem is that after creating the `Player` I need the `PlayerModel` and `PlayerView` instances to create the `Board`.

My solution is to "wrap" the `PlayerModel`, `PlayerView` and `PlayerController` in a `Player` class that only has these 3 fields and 3 `getters`; pass the `Player` to the `BoardFactory` and inside the factory use the 3 getter to get the `View` and the `Model` needed by the Board.

I'm doing something like this :

```
PlayerFactory pFactory = new PlayerFactory();
Player player = pFactory.build("HUMAN");
BoardFactory bFactory = new BoardFactory();
Board board = bFactory.build(player);
```

My worries are about the "wrapper" `Player` class.
Does it make sense to have a class just to hold 3 objects ?
Is there a better way to pass the dependencies to the `Board` without using a IoC container?

Comment: How does the `Board` use `PlayerView`, `PlayerController` and `PlayerModel`?

Comment: @ChetanKinger The `Board` uses the `PlayerView` to add to its own `View` (for rendering purposes) and uses the `PlayerModel` to check for example if the player can move in a specific position.
The `Board` class its itself a wrapper for `BoardView`, `BoardModel` and `BoardContoller`

Comment: I have attempted to provide an answer based on my understanding. Take a look and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Thank you for you answer. The problem is that I nave to use the MVC pattern, so I don't want to pass both the view and the model to the controller.

Comment: No problem. Just curious as to why would you "have" to use a particular pattern?

Comment: @ChetanKinger It's one of the request of my assignement. And I need to change the "graphic" view with a "CLI' view, so the MVC is not so bad after alla.

Comment: You can still change the`Graphic` view with the `CLI` view with my approach. But if you insist on using MVC, you might have to redesign your classes from scratch as the way you have them right now would require you to use an empty wrapper that does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Your overall approach looks good. Although, there are a couple of changes I would make :

`PlayerController` and `Player` seem to have the same responsibility. I would get rid of `Player` completely and just use a `PlayerController` instead

The pseudo-code would look like this :

```
 public class PlayerController {
    private PlayerView playerView;
    private PlayerModel playerModel;
    //constructor that intializes playerView and playerModel

    public void render() { playerView.render() }

    public void moveForward(int steps) {
       if(playerModel.canMoveForward()) {
            playerView.moveForward(steps);
       }
    }
 }
```

Similarly, you can get rid of `Board` and just have a `BoardController` instead.  `BoardController` can then depend on `PlayerController` instead of depending on `Player`. The pseudo-code for this would look something like :

```
 public class BoardController {
     private PlayerController playerController;
     private BoardView boardView;
     private BoardModel boardModel;
     //constructor that intializes the dependencies 

    public void render() { 
        playerController.render();
        boardView.render();
    }

    public void movePlayerForward(int steps) {
       if(!boardModel.isGameOver()) {
        playerController.moveForward(steps);
       }
    }
 }
```

This way, you get rid of `Player` and `Board` classes that were really not doing much. Alternately, you can rename the above classes to `Player` and `Board`. Another advantage of the above pseudo-code is that you also end up making your code more readable by implementing the `Tell Dont Ask` principle.